# Joining other sites fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

If I try try to upvote an answer on Life Hacks, I am invited to join. Right.

Then trying to join Life Hacks with my Google account results in an error message saying that an error occurred which I should report here.

Comment: And it really is annoying that one cannot post for one minute after seeing that adding one of the missing mandatory tags is required to post (i.e. after the first post attempt failed)..

Comment: This seems to be site specific? Or maybe only on beta sites or something? I have the same problem on life hacks, but am now a new member of server fault.. (Incidentally, that 'sign up process' is beautiful - top ux)

Comment: Dunno. Don't wanna join a site just to test.

Comment: Haha, apparently you can self delete..I'll have to try when I'm at my laptop later!

Comment: @Chris You can, but only if you did nothing on the site :) Once you do anything there, this link disappears.

Comment: @nicael I upvoted momentarily, and immediately removed it, to check I actually WAS signed in. Thought this might not count, but I just got the badge, so I guess it's a support email for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats not "other sites", but *only* [Japanese Stack Overflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com) and [Life Hacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com), as they are both in private beta now.

Seems that you have a problem logging into Life Hacks. Did you commit to this proposal or have an invitation link?

If you did, just click an invitation link and create account.

If you didn't, you **won't have an ability to log in until it will be public beta**. You can only be a side viewer, and only through the app (therefore that might be bug - site don't allow even reading, but app do).

Comment: Not entirely true. If you go to area51 to the proposal, it has a link you can click on in order to gain access to the site (still need to register/login).

Comment: @Oded I thought that I can log in to private beta without commitment only in the first day... Where is it located?

Comment: There is a big "Visit the site now" link. Follow that to get to the signup form.

Comment: @Oded No, if you don't have an invitation link, this will just bring you to "Warning, this site is in private beta, you must have received an invitation link, click it". It will work only in some few time after the site's private beta begin.

Comment: I just did that. Didn't have an account on it, clicked the link and was able to register. Did you try it?

Comment: @Oded I did. As for me, it works only till the end of the first private beta day, if I am not mistaken. But anyway, now it doesn't work, I can click only invitation link in my email.

Comment: We _specifically_ added code to enable registration if coming from the area51 proposal. Thinking is that if someone is interested enough in the proposal to follow the link, they should be OK to register.

Comment: @Oded Ok. I just did it. Cleared cookies. Went to the site. Doesn't allow to log in. Did the same from the proposal. Still doesn't work. Only invitation link works.

Comment: Try with an anonymous browser window. Go to [the proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64409/lifehacks), follow the big link (**specifically** from the "Visit the site now!" link - not any other link).

Comment: @Oded Strange, works on my phone, but not in the computer. Anyway, that provides an ability to log in to any person: even if they go directly to the site (not proposal), there is a link to the proposal. Click the link and click the link to the site from proposal. You are here. Why does it say then that invitation link is needed, if no invitation link is actually needed?

Comment: Probably a historical artifact - no one changed it after it was updated.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in 1.4.1.

The app now displays the following message when you try interacting with a private beta that you are not already a member of:

> You cannot interact with *{siteName}* because it is currently in a private beta.